# "video system not initialized" While closing pygame window

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have two similar code snippets. Both run fine but One displays the error When i close the pygame window

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nabeel/Devalopment/Python/aaa.py", line 92, in <module>
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Here is the piece of code which throws error

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

done = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
pygame.display.set_caption("my_game")

while not done:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

and here's the one which does not

```
import pygame

done = False
pygame.init()

screen_size = [320,240]

white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

paddle_x = 0
paddle_y = 0
vel_x = 0
vel_y = 0

gutter = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("mygame")



while not done:

    screen.fill(black)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                vel_y += 2
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:    
                vel_y -= 2
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                vel_x -= 2
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:    
                vel_x += 2

    paddle_x += vel_x
    paddle_y += vel_y    


    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(gutter,0),(gutter,screen_size[1]))
    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(screen_size[0]-gutter,0),(screen_size[0]-gutter,screen_size[1]))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,[screen_size[0]/2,screen_size[1]/2,10,10],0)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,[paddle_x+5,paddle_y],[paddle_x+5,paddle_y+30],gutter)
    pygame.display.flip()




pygame.quit()
```

While these two do not do any thing harful I was just curious to what is causing all this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the pygame.quit() in this block:

```
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    done = True
    pygame.quit()
```

The idea is that when `pygame.quit()` is called, the whole module is uninitialized and hence if more method calls of the module are found (like `pygame.display.flip()`) they will throw an error :)

If you wish to keep the pygame.quit() method call in the above conditional if statement, what you could do is import the `sys` module and below `pygame.quit()` add a `sys.exit()`.

Both ways should work pretty well :)
Hope that helped,

Cheers! Alex

Comment: Another possibility would be to put the game loop into a function then call return right pygame.quit() to exit the function.